# After successful run of the magento data migration tool from 1.9.2.1 to 2.3.5-p1 orders do not display line items

Tags: magento2, orders, data-migration-tool

I was able to get the Data Migration Tool to transfer our site's data and settings from v1.9.2.1 to v2.3.5-p1.

There is one small problem that I can't figure out though.

When I view orders on the admin side, the section titled "Items Ordered" is always empty.
But the order line items are in the database.

- This returns one row as expected for this order

`select * from sales_order WHERE entity_id = 77002;`

- This returns 5 rows as expected for this order

`select * from sales_order_item WHERE order_id = 77002;`

I am still in the early stages of learning Magento.
Thank you.

---

**Edit 1:**
I ran tail on the /var/www/html/var/log/debug.log   and got the following errors  when refreshing the admin view order page:

```
[2020-06-18 15:46:22] main.CRITICAL: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\Filter\TruncateFilter\Result, Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Filter\TruncateFilter\Result::__construct() must be of the type string, null given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121 [] []
[2020-06-18 15:46:22] main.CRITICAL: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\Filter\TruncateFilter\Result [] []
```

Comment: Check the log file if any errors are logged.

Comment: Did you have any custom order attributes in Magento 1? if you migrated using --auto then it might cause an error. Check your eav_attributes table in M2, remove attributes that aren't used in your M2 install.

Comment: @Ricky, thank you for your reply we are looking into what you said. I will update you when i have learned.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1, there are **sales_flat_order** table and **sales_flat_order_item** table. However, in Magento 2, they are renamed to **sales_order** and **sales_order_item**. Please try to back up and run again the data migration tool

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response, after looking at it more closely i discovered that I was looking at the wrong database. All the correct tables were transferred but the order line items are still not showing up in the admin. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @DonMoore, you're welcome! please give me an upvote and accept my answer as a solution to help others who are in the same situation can find the right answer.